# How to call window installer from Java Application

Tags: java

We work on the Java application .Our the application we need to call some service which is a window installer and that when run from the command prompt accept the input file and gives the result as an output file.
Java application is on Linux and window service is on window so my question is that how can i call this window service from my java code.
I thought of writing some kind of a scheduler but how will i make sure that the scheduler runs only when the input file gets copied on the Window env from the Linux m/c and how will i get back the result that the installer has run the programme and generated the output file.

Please help in suggesting some idea.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to execute the external program of installer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121990/pass-string-as-params-from-one-java-app-to-another) can help you with that, and please read before that [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)