# ExecutorService awaitTermination gets stuck

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I made a fixed size thread pool with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)`, and I executed 10 `Runnable` objects. I set breakpoints and traced through the execution. However, `fixedSizeThreadPool.awaitTermination()` does not allow me to continue even though all the tasks are done.

Basically:

```
ExecutorService fixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    fixedSizeThreadPool.execute(myRunables[i]);
}
try {
    fixedSizeThreadPool.awaitTermination(timeout, timeoutUnits);
} catch (Exception e) { }
System.out.println("done!");
```

But this always gets stuck on `awaitTermination`. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you please show your ThreadPool declaration

Comment: You have to call shutdown first to make exec service to terminate.

Comment: maybe -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121990/pass-string-as-params-from-one-java-app-to-another

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As Peter pointed out, `shutdown()` must be called first.

source: [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Comment: So if I want to keep reusing the threadpool, I should use invokeAll, and keep checking the list of Futures until they're all completed?

Comment: that's correct - `awaitTermination` is only used in the context of shutting it down

Comment: @kevin: invokeall returns only after ALL tasks have completed, either normally or with exception. You check Futures to get results in this case, not to see if they have completed (they have).

Comment: @Peter you're absolutely right. I mistakenly thought that invokeAll was not blocking.

Comment: @Peter - nice catch. I assume this is what he wants to achieve though based on his code.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [ExecutorService#invokeAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). It blocks until all tasks are done or the timeout is reached. It's a little cleaner than using `shutdown`, if your ExecutorService contains other tasks as well especially scheduled tasks. These would also be affected by a call to `shutdown`.