# How to ensure a task is executed upon closing a Java Desktop Application?

Tags: java, swing

This is a "best practices" type of question. AFAIK there are two approaches (and possibly more..) when needing to execute a task prior to JVM shutdown:

1. Add a `WindowListener` to the container and override the `windowClosing` event
2. Add a shutdown hook (i.e. [`Runtime.addShutdownHook`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29))

Which approach is the "preferred" way when it comes to Java Desktop applications? Is there a "preferred" way?

Comment: my question what do you really to want to know, +1 for very strange question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not best practices, not preferred way, only to close current JVM instance and very simple,

1) `Top-LevelContainer#setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`

2) add `WindowListener`

```
     WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                  "Are You Sure to Close Application?", "Exit Confirmation", 
                  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                  null, null, null);
            if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                Top-LevelContainer#setVisible(false);
                // clean-up everything 

                // on error display  JOptionPane with error mgs but from
                // another JVM instance, e.g.jar file, see add 3.)
                System.exit(1); //in some cases not works System.exit(0);
            }
     }
```

3) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121990/pass-string-as-params-from-one-java-app-to-another) is rest for how to display error message from another, new JVM instance

Comment: Don't use magic numbers! Does 0 mean Yes or No?

Comment: @camickr right one of my wrong habits