# How to restart a java program within the program

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a small Java game using Swing for school, and we need to implement a button that "starts a new game" when pressed. The problem is, the game takes multiple parameters from String[] args, so I can't just call the "main" function (where everything is instansiated) again from another class. Any way to do this?

Comment: Move the code from the `main` method to a class which you can configure and resinstaniate

Comment: The broad answer is that it depends on what you do with those variables from `main`; it isn't like they've outright *disappeared* unless you're overwriting them...

Comment: Possible duplicates [Restart Swing Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390481/restart-swing-application)

Answer (score 0):

You certainly *can* call `main()` from inside your application.  But it's also certainly not what you want to do.  Instead try moving the instantiation code into another function, most likely a constructor of some type of Game object.  Then you can instantiate a new game from both main as well as some kind of `restart` function without any unintended consequences of calling `main` from inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to run a program. Unless your button and game are in the same package, be sure to import it (which will look like `import packageName.className)`.

```
JButton newbutton = new JButton("New");
    newbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                      new className(); //run the class you want to here
                 }
            });
        }
    });
```

If you have any questions about this code, please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to lauch your program before exit it.
`Runtime rs = Runtime. getRuntime(); try { rs. exec("java -jar your_restartable_program.jar"); }`

Comment: In addition System.exit(0);