# Java communication between 2 applications

Tags: java, communication

Considering `application_A` on a `machine_1` needs information about `machine_2`, provided by `application_B` (which is located on `machine_2`) and that both machines are in the same network, what would you guys suggest to be the easiest way of implementing the communication between the 2? (I was thinking simple socket connection).

Note: the information required is something in the lines of a few bytes, so nothing big.

Comment: there are a [few ways, depends of...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121990/pass-string-as-params-from-one-java-app-to-another)

Comment: Here you may find a simple and complete example: http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can either use socket based communication or Java [RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html).
2. I would recommend Java RMI as its easier and saves you from handling raw socket communication.
3. If you are familiar with Spring framework, then writing RMI application in spring is very easy. Check [Exposing services using RMI](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/remoting.html) (Heading 17.2)

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to implement this but they all come down to one thing: communication over sockets.
If the information is only some bytes, implementing the sockets themselves is probably your best bet, if things start to get bigger, you might want to look into some middleware.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a server program on `Machine2` using `ServerSocket` and a client program in `Machine1` can request for info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try web services. JAX-RS would be the simplest.