# Calling an external jar in classpath from a Java Application

Tags: java, swing

I have two java Swing applications and I need to be able to execute the first one from the second. I have compiled the first to a jar and placed it in the classpath of the second. I am calling the main class of the first jar from the application but all I see is a blank frame.
The Main of my first Jar looks like this:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
public class AskulLibrary extends Frame implements Runnable{
final Frame frame;
    public AskulLibrary(Frame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public void run() {
        frame.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        // Throw a nice little title page up on the screen first
        new Splash().showSplash(3000);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new AskulLibrary(new JLibrary()));
    }
}
```

I'm calling this main class from the second application like this:

```
import com.AskulLibrary;
import java.awt.Frame;
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
       AskulLibrary lib;
       Frame frame;
     public MainFrame(){
    frame = new new Frame();
    lib = new AskulLibrary (frame);
    lib.run();

}

}
```

I'm doing something wrong somewhere because instead of initializing the first Jar I am getting an empty Frame. I do not want to run the jar like this although this is running the first program successfully:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar lib/Myfirstjar.jar");
```

Comment: 1) `frame = new new Frame();`  That would not compile.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- why not to use implemented methods in official API, [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)
- (before `Splash Screen` was implemented in official APIs) use `JWindow`/`JDialog` but without using `Runnable#Thread`, use the quite strict logics described about `Event Dispatch Thread` in [InitialThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) instead, for both [Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)
- see my [question about reverse order, similair, but with interactive logics,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121990/pass-string-as-params-from-one-java-app-to-another)